# CMake FindwxWidgets fails only on first invocation of "configure" command

Tags: cmake, wxwidgets

I have the following code to try find wxWidgets 3.1 pre-built libraries using CMake 3.7.1.

```
set(wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR M:/wxWidgets)
set(wxWidgets_LIB_DIR M:/wxWidgets/lib/gcc510TDM_x64_dll)
set(wxWidgets_CONFIGURATION mswud)
find_package(wxWidgets 3.1 REQUIRED COMPONENTS core base stc)
include(${wxWidgets_USE_FILE})
target_link_libraries(MyTarget ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES})
```

The generator is "CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles". And it is on Windows 7. So the FindwxWidgets module's search style is "win32".

The strange thing is that this code always fails on the first invocation of "configure" command/button, when the CMake cache is not yet set. And it will succeed on subsequent invocation of "configure". And the error message is

```
CMake Error at M:/cmake-3.7.1-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:138 (message):
  Could NOT find wxWidgets (missing: wxWidgets_LIBRARIES
  wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS) (Required is at least version "3.1")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  M:/cmake-3.7.1-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  M:/cmake-3.7.1-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindwxWidgets.cmake:929 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:16 (find_package)
```

I'm new to CMake. Is this normal? Is FindwxWidgets module supposed to work this way?

Below are the contents of CMake cache after the first (failed) "configure":

```
//Cleared.
wxWidgets_LIB_DIR:PATH=wxWidgets_LIB_DIR-NOTFOUND
...
...
//wxWidgets_LIB_DIR
WX_LIB_DIR:INTERNAL=wxWidgets_LIB_DIR-NOTFOUND
//wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR
WX_ROOT_DIR:INTERNAL=M:/wxWidgets
```

Below are the contents of CMake cache after subsequent (successful) "configure":

```
//Path to a file.
_filename:FILEPATH=M:/wxWidgets/include/wx/version.h

//Set wxWidgets configuration (mswud;mswu)
wxWidgets_CONFIGURATION:STRING=mswud

//Cleared.
wxWidgets_LIB_DIR:PATH=wxWidgets_LIB_DIR-NOTFOUND

//Location of wxWidgets resource file compiler binary (wxrc)
wxWidgets_wxrc_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=wxWidgets_wxrc_EXECUTABLE-NOTFOUND
...
...
//Details about finding wxWidgets
FIND_PACKAGE_MESSAGE_DETAILS_wxWidgets:INTERNAL=[M:/wxWidgets/lib/gcc510TDM_x64_dll/libwxmsw31ud_core.a;M:/wxWidgets/lib/gcc510TDM_x64_dll/libwxbase31ud.a;M:/wxWidgets/lib/gcc510TDM_x64_dll/libwxmsw31ud_stc.a;M:/wxWidgets/lib/gcc510TDM_x64_dll/libwxpngd.a;M:/wxWidgets/lib/gcc510TDM_x64_dll/libwxtiffd.a;M:/wxWidgets/lib/gcc510TDM_x64_dll/libwxjpegd.a;M:/wxWidgets/lib/gcc510TDM_x64_dll/libwxzlibd.a;M:/wxWidgets/lib/gcc510TDM_x64_dll/libwxregexud.a;M:/wxWidgets/lib/gcc510TDM_x64_dll/libwxexpatd.a;winmm;comctl32;rpcrt4;wsock32][M:/wxWidgets/lib/gcc510TDM_x64_dll/mswud;M:/wxWidgets/include][v3.1.0(3.1)]
//wxWidgets_LIB_DIR
WX_LIB_DIR:INTERNAL=M:/wxWidgets/lib/gcc510TDM_x64_dll
//wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR
WX_ROOT_DIR:INTERNAL=M:/wxWidgets
```

I omitted keys that are for individual wxWidgets components, such as "WX_zlib:FILEPATH", or "WX_zlib-ADVANCED:INTERNAL", etc.

Comment: `Is this normal?` - No, normally search algorithm should give *persistent* results. Code of `FindwxWidgets.cmake` uses some "clean" logic when it finds things under directories other than `wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR` or `wxWidgets_LIB_DIR`. Probably, such logic cause the behaviour you observe. Could you provide **content of CMake cache** after the first(failed) "configure" and the second one? This would give a key. Only cache entries started with `wx` or `WX_` are interested. BTW, the example uses driver letter in upper case (`C:/`), but your code use lower case (`m:/`). This may have a sence.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Based on your comment, I reran cmake-gui and captured CMake cache contents. I updated the question accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: @Tsyvarev I found a workaround. I removed set commands for both `wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR` and `wxWidgets_LIB_DIR`. Instead, I set the environment variable `wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR`, and moved pre-built library files into one of the locations that FindwxWidgets.cmake will look for.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, using the generator for Visual Studio 2015x64, until I added the line setting WX_ROOT_DIR:

```
SET(WX_ROOT_DIR ${wxwidgets_path})
SET(wxWidgets_CONFIGURATION mwsu)
SET(wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR ${wxwidgets_path})
SET(wxWidgets_LIB_DIR ${wxwidgets_path}/vc_x64_lib)
FIND_PACKAGE(wxWidgets REQUIRED QUIET)
```

Comment: I can confirm using `${WX_ROOT_DIR}` without cache works on PSDK 7.1 + wxWidgets 3.0.5 + CMake 3.22.3.

Answer (score 0):

Script `FindwxWidgets.cmake` has non-intuitive logic, so hinting with *wxWidgets_LIB_DIR* path is tricky:

1. Hint *wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR* should be in some **canonical form**, where driver letter is uppercase:

   ```
   set(wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR "M:/wxWidgets")
   ```
2. Hint *wxWidgets_LIB_DIR* should be **cached variable**:

   ```
   set(wxWidgets_LIB_DIR "M:/wxWidgets/lib/gcc510TDM_x64_dll"
       CACHE PATH "wxWidgets_LIB_DIR ")
   ```

---

This is what happens in your case.

First "configure" invocation:

1. Cache is empty.
2. The script detects (with `find_path`) root directory of the library, and stores result into *WX_ROOT_PATH* cached variable.
3. The script finds that value of *WX_ROOT_PATH* variable **differs** from value of *wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR*. Because of that, it modifies value of cached variable *WX_ROOT_PATH* to value of *wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR*.
4. Additionaly, because of difference detected at previous step, the script set cached variable *wxWidgets_LIB_DIR* to `-NOTFOUND`.
5. The script tries to detect (with `find_path`) library directory **without hint** *wxWidgets_LIB_DIR*. Of course, this fails. Result (`-NOTFOUND`) would be stored into cached variable *wxWidgets_LIB_DIR*, but it already has this value.

Setting cached variable *wxWidgets_LIB_DIR* at step 4 **clears non-cache variable** with the same name, so futher searches are **failed**.

On the second "configure" invocation:

1. Variables *WX_ROOT_PATH* and *wxWidgets_LIB_DIR* are already in cache.
2. find_path() do nothing, as *WX_ROOT_PATH* is already in cache.
3. Values of *WX_ROOT_PATH* (cached) and *wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR*(non-cached) are the same.
4. Setting of cached variable *wxWidgets_LIB_DIR* is not performed (whole step isn't performed).
5. `find_path` still cannot find the library path, but value of cached variable *wxWidgets_LIB_DIR* is **already** `-NOTFOUND`, so it is not modified.

Non-cached variable *wxWidgets_LIB_DIR* (which is set by yours) is not cleared, and it is used in the futher searches. (non-cache variable shadows cache one, see `* Variable types in CMake *` in [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/set.html) for `set` command). So this configuration **succeed**.

Comment: I really like your answer. I modified the code as suggested, it consistently failed with the same error every time. :(  But I think that you point me towards the right direction.

Comment: Oops, actually it is *wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR* cache variable which is set at the step 2 by `find_path`. So, step 3 at the first "configure" invocation is inevitable and it clears *wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR*. As a fast workaround, you may set both *wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR* and  *WX_ROOT_DIR* cached variables:  `set(wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR "M:/wxWidgets" CACHE PATH "wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR")`, `set(WX_ROOT_DIR "M:/wxWidgets" CACHE PATH "wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR")`, but this is a hack, of course. I will think about nicer decision.

Comment: I tried to set both hints as cache entries, and even with `FORCE`. It either always fails, or fails on first invocation. I don't think those hints actually work.

Comment: @thebat Did you find something that did work?

Comment: @J.Gwinner I hacked around it. It is not pretty but works.

 (1) Removed line `set(wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR M:/wxWidgets)`, and set an environment variable called `wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR`.
 (2) Removed line `set(wxWidgets_LIB_DIR M:/wxWidgets/lib/gcc510TDM_x64_dll)`, and put wxWidgets DLL files into the default folder expected by the find wxWidgets cmake module, i.e. `{Your wxWidgets' Root}\lib\gcc_dll`.

Comment: @thebat Thanks! I'll see if that fixes our problem.

Comment: What fixed our problem was to do a complete build of WxWidgets. Turns out, the previous version was checked in, but just the DLL's needed for our project by a prev. dev. The new CMake doesn't like that, it won't detect the library until it's the full library.