# CMake on Linux: missing wxWidgets_LIBRARIES

Tags: cmake, build, wxwidgets, cmakelists-options

I'm compiling a program from sources, which uses wxWidgets on Linux.

I have set the following variables in CMakeLists.txt:

```
SET(wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR ~/Downloads/wxWidgets-3.1.3)
SET(wxWidgets_LIBRARIES ~/Downloads/wxWidgets-3.1.3/lib)
SET(wxWidgets_LIB_DIR ~/Downloads/wxWidgets-3.1.3/lib)
SET(wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS ~/Downloads/wxWidgets-3.1.3/include/wx)
#SET(wxWidgets_VERSION_STRING "3.1.3")
SET(wxWidgets_CONFIGURATION mswu)
SET(WX_ROOT_DIR ~/Downloads/wxWidgets-3.1.3)
```

And get an error:

```
Could NOT find wxWidgets (missing: wxWidgets_LIBRARIES)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindwxWidgets.cmake:953 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:173 (FIND_PACKAGE)
```

*CMakeLists.txt:173* contains the following:

```
FIND_PACKAGE(wxWidgets REQUIRED base core aui xrc html xml adv gl net qa)
```

Any idea what I need to do?

Comment: CMake [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindwxWidgets.html) recommends setting `wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR` and a few others for configuration but `wxWidgets_LIBRARIES` variable should be populated by the `find_package()` call itself. Also, it is **not** recommended to use the `~` path shortcut in CMakeLists.txt files as it can cause issues.

Comment: @bb8, you should use wx-config under Linux to compile your own code. Use `/path/o/wx-config/wx-config --cxxflags` and 1/path/to/wx-config/wx-config --libs`

Comment: i'm on virtual box, so i changed `~` to `/home/user-name`. also set `wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR`, `wxWidgets_LIB_DIR` and `wxWidgets_CONFIGURATION` but it's still the same error.

Comment: @Igor with CMake? how?

Comment: my wxWidgets-3.1.3/lib contains abicheck.sh, vms.opt, vms_gtk.opt, vms_gtk2.opt, vms_x11_univ.opt. is that correct?

Comment: @bb8, you can try to do SET(wxWidgets_LIBRARIES `/home/user-name//Downloads/wxWidgets-3.1.3/buildGTK/wx-config --libs`). But its easier to install an IDE (Anjuta) and work with plain old and simple configure and friends.

Comment: You might consider reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41578736/3987854) response to an earlier question, as it may also apply to your situation.

Comment: i've seen that but it didn't help :(
@Igor i tried setting, no change :( tried installing anjuta, and got bunch of "not found" errors (e.g. libgda4)

Comment: @bb8, which OS do you use? You might try installing CodeBlocks instead. Anjuta is just one option. CodeBlocks, CodeLite are another ones.

Comment: I tried both on linux and windows. i get the same error :( why do i need to install those IDEs?